# unable to create outlet in xamarin for imageview.App crashes

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

i have used an imageview in the ios builder in visual studio whose refrence is automatically connected to my viewcontroller class and when i do set image to that imageview my app crashes with an error "This class is not key-value complient for the key image__"
As i am new to xamarin i am not aware if we need to do anything else inorder to make relation from storyboard to the class variable for access that particular outlet object.Please suggest me if you have any advice?

Comment: Check the thread :  https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/38992/

Answer (score 0):

Open the storyboard in visual studio and then open properties pad. Select the image view and give Name in the identity option. Outlets from Xcode did not work in xamarin.

For example, your view controller name is TestView and you give the Name to image view as MyImage. Now there is one more file named TestView.designer.cs open that file and you will see that Outlets are generated in that file.

[image]

Comment: I have already done this. It is created in viewcontroller.designer.cs but when i use the same in viewcontroller.cs then app crashes with the message "This class is not key-value complient for the key image__".

Comment: can you share your code? You have assign Identifier to storyboard for viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

You might have accidentally removed the connection.

Is your imageView name: `image__`?

Given if the imageView is in `ViewController.cs`, look at the Solution Explorer, expand and find the `ViewController.designer.cs` and remove the `imageView` or `image__`(in your case) Outlet and whatever that's related to it and then re-link the Outlet again.

Comment: This is not the case there is only one single outlet which is present in viewcontroller.designer.cs. Even image__ appers in the suggestion while writing code but still app crashes with the same message at runtime

Comment: The problem is your Storyboard doesn't know about `image__` and your `ViewController.designer.cs` has that hanging Outlet. You have either removed or renamed the outlet. Easiest solution is to remove that and recreate the Outlet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the refrence was not working properly. I just removed the  image outlet and viewController class and closed the project.Then i started creating that same class from very scratch and created the outlet from the storyboard. That was it. Everything started working COOL..!!!

I hope restarting the project helped me and it can help you too.Good Luck.